# R assigning names to lists in matrix

Tags: r, sapply, mapply

I'm iterating a function through each parameter value of Lx for each value of Ly. The function produces a list and then the lists are put into a matrix. I'm trying to give names to the resultant lists so that I know what combination of parameters (Lx and Ly) was used for each run of the function. See reproducible example below:

```
test_sim <- function(Lx, Ly){
  results=list()
  ret <- runif(3, min=0, max=100)
  results[[1]]=ret
  names(results)[1]=paste(Lx,Ly,sep = "_")
  return(results)
}
Lx <- seq(0.25,0.5,0.25)
Ly <- seq(0.05, 0.10, 0.05)
blam <- sapply(Lx, function(x) mapply(test_sim, x, Ly))
```

However, that appears to only name the first two rows of the matrix. How can I name each list appropriately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lapply` instead of `sapply`.

This will produce a nested list:

```
# This produces a nested list
blam <- lapply(Lx, function(x) mapply(test_sim, x, Ly))
blam;
#[[1]]
#[[1]]$`0.25_0.05`
#[1] 80.11677 60.42781 83.07715
#
#[[1]]$`0.25_0.1`
#[1] 34.98122 13.24191 64.38831
#
#
#[[2]]
#[[2]]$`0.5_0.05`
#[1] 56.466308  7.158086 66.655274
#
#[[2]]$`0.5_0.1`
#[1] 66.88615 16.05237 43.16896
```

You can then flatten the list using `unlist(..., recursive = FALSE)`:

```
# Flatten nested list
unlist(blam, recursive = FALSE);
#$`0.25_0.05`
#[1] 80.11677 60.42781 83.07715
#
#$`0.25_0.1`
#[1] 34.98122 13.24191 64.38831
#
#$`0.5_0.05`
#[1] 56.466308  7.158086 66.655274
#
#$`0.5_0.1`
#[1] 66.88615 16.05237 43.16896
```

Comment: Yes! It works. I did not know about `recursive` in `unlist`.